# animate function doesn't work with colors and anchors

Tags: jquery, background, jquery-animate

I have problem with animate background color in navigate anchors:

```
$(this).animate({ backgroundColor: "black" }, 1000);
```

with size (like width) works correct.

Why I should to do to fade backgdround color?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, colors doesn't work with the animation built into jQuery. Use the [color animation plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color) for that.